# PostgreSQL. Создание роли с названием из киррилических символов

Tags: postgresql, кодировка

Не могу зайди под пользователем, чье имя состоит из киррилических символов.
Например, в pgadmin или через psql создаю юзера:

```
CREATE USER Тест WITH PASSWORD '1234';
```

Затем при попытке войти под ним вылетает ошибка:

```
2018-07-12 17:43:45 MSK ВАЖНО:  пользователь "Тест" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
2018-07-12 17:43:45 MSK ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  Роль "Тест" не существует.
Подключение соответствует строке 97 в pg_hba.conf: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"
```

Хотя она, конечно же, существует.
Я так понимаю тут что-то с кодировкой. Но не вижу путей, как можно исправить эту проблему. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если вы не добавляли пользвателя в pg_hba.conf, то скорее всего вам просто надо указать хост. То есть, `psql -U Тест -h 127.0.0.1`. Юзеров со внешних ПГ по умолчанию по паролю не пускает.

Comment: @Ainar-G в pg_hba.conf у меня на всех нужных ip стоит                                                       
 host    all        all             ............              md5

Comment: @Ainar-G, да и в общем-то пользователи с английским именем без проблем логинятся, так что проблема не в этом

Answer (score 0):

```
postgres=# create user "Тест" with password '1234';
CREATE ROLE

postgres=# create database "тест_база";
CREATE DATABASE

postgres=# alter database "тест_база" owner to "Тест";
ALTER DATABASE


alexandr@~$ psql -U Тест тест_база
psql (10.4)
Введите "help", чтобы получить справку.

тест_база=> \c
Вы подключены к базе данных "тест_база" как пользователь "Тест".
тест_база=>
```

Comment: не помогает, более того у меня уже есть бд, и мне для нее нужно создать юзеров